# Kotlin explain me about Backing Fields

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have been looking at Kotlin official tutorial. I came across the topic called **Backing Fields**

It says,

> Classes in Kotlin cannot have fields. However, sometimes it is necessary to have a backing field when using custom accessors. For these purposes, Kotlin provides an automatic backing field which can be accessed using the field identifier:

```
var counter = 0 // the initializer value is written directly to the backing field
    set(value) {
        if (value >= 0) field = value
    }
```

I got the above from [this official link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields)

My question is, is the "field" pointing to counter variable ?

Can someone please provide me an example for the backing field or describe me in an understanding word ?

Comment: Why negative at the beginning ?

Comment: For one the code you posted isn't the entire code example. People shouldn't have to go to external links to get the full picture.  Yes, it looks like  `field` is a special keyword that aids in mutating setters.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Consider this class

```
class SomeClass {
    var counter: Int = 0
        set(value) {
            if (value >= 0) field = value
        }
}
```

In Android Studio go to `Main menu -> Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin Bytecode` and click `Decompile` in the Kotlin bytecode panel.

What you see is the equivalent code in Java.

```
public final class SomeClass {
   private int counter;

   public final int getCounter() {
      return this.counter;
   }

   public final void setCounter(int value) {
      if(value >= 0) {
         this.counter = value;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You have paved the way to find out other issues as well... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

The `field` keyword allows you to assign a value inside a custom setter. In kotlin `counter = 3` will call `set(3)`. So if you would define

```
var counter=0
set(value){
    counter = value
}
```

It would recursively call itself until your stack is full and your process crashes.
The `field` keyword assigns the value directly without calling the setter again.

Answer (score 5):

> A Backing Field is just a field that will be generated for a property
>   in a class only if it uses the default implementation of at least one
>   of the accessors

Backing field is generated only if a property uses the default implementation of getter/setter. If you see the following code with perspective of `Java`. It looks correct. However in "kotlin" it’ll throw Exception.

```
  class User{ 
       var firstName : String //backing field generated
      get() = firstName 
      set(value) {
           firstName = value
      } 
      var lastName : String //backing field generated 
      get() = lastName 
      set(value) {
           lastName = value
      }
      val name : String //no backing field generated 
      get() = "{$firstName $lastName}" 
      var address : String = "XYZ" //^because there is no default //^implementation of an accessor 
 }
```

In Kotlin the above code snippet will throw StackOverflow because when we access or set property "first-name" or "last name" the default accessor will be called. So in Kotlin "user.firstName = "value"” is same as Java’s "user.setFirstName("value")".

So when "set(value) {firstName = "value"} " is called, then a recursive callhappens and compiler throws a Exception exception because we are calling setter inside the setter.

Solution to this problem is to user backing fields. In Kotlin a backing field can be accessed using "field" keyword inside accessors. Take a look at corrected code snippet below.

```
 class User{ 
      var firstName : String get() = field 
      set(value) {
           field = value
      } 
      var lastName : String get() = field 
      set(value) {
           field = value} 
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

How it works , let's understand by an example , consider this

```
class Person {
   var name: String = ""
}
```

If nothing is specified, the property(**name**) uses the default getter and setter. It can, of course,
be modified to run whatever custom behaviour you need, without having to change
the existing code:

So if want set custom behaviour to name property than we modify above class to this

```
class Person {

   var name: String = ""
   get() = field.toUpperCase()
   set(value) {
     field = "Name: $value"
  }


}
```

If the property needs access to its own value in a custom getter or setter (as in this
case), it requires the creation of a **backing field**. It can be accessed by using field, a
reserved word, and will be automatically created by the compiler when it finds that
it’s being used.